# Вытянуть данные с JSON (AsyncHttpClient parsing)

Tags: android, json, парсер, asynchttpclient

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вытянуть "sity_name"

```
    final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(getActivity(), "http://restoran.returnt.ru/", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                try {


                    Log.d("wwwwww", response.getString("data"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Проверьте подключение к интернету", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject response) {
            if (statusCode == 400) {
                Log.d("eeeee", String.valueOf(statusCode));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Проверьте подключение к интернету", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("data").get(0).getJSONObject("city").getString("city_name");
```